# convert list of list into array of bytes

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, wav

I have list of integer list ,I'm working in shift coding so i have different length code for each stream, so i use list of list for each one because its re-sizable, i tried to store all the stream in one array of bytes and i fail so how can i converted to array of bytes...

like this:

```
list[10 item]
list[0] of list[5 item][0,0,1,0,3]
list[1] of list[4 item][0,0,1,1]
```

and convert it to array of bytes...

like this:
    array[bytes]=[0,0,1,0,3,0,0,1,1,3,0,0,.....];
the count of item in the inner list different from one item to another....

Comment: Do you have any code that compiles? This is difficult to understand.

Comment: i found this solution in stack-over but the question is not appropriate to answer var listOfArrays = new List<byte[]>();
var flattenedList = listOfArrays.SelectMany(bytes => bytes);
var byteArray = flattenedList.ToArray();

Comment: i want to convert list of list to array of byte var listOfArrays = new List<byte[]>(); var flattenedList = listOfArrays.SelectMany(bytes => bytes); var byteArray = flattenedList.ToArray(); like this i think

Comment: @Layan So what's wrong with using LINQ (apart from performance)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is what you're looking for:

```
List<List<int>> foo = new List<List<int>> { new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }, new List<int> { 1, 2 } };
var flat = foo.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Flat is now: 1, 2, 3, 1, 2

Answer (score 1):

SelectMany gives you what you need:

```
var list = new List<List<int>>();
list.Add(new List<int>() {1, 2, 3});
list.Add(new List<int>() {4, 5, 6});
list.Add(new List<int>() {7, 8, 9});
var combined = list.SelectMany(x => x).Select(x=>(byte)x).ToArray();
```

At the end, you have a flattened array of bytes from a list of list of ints. Sounds like exactly what you're going for.

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with LINQ then you can "flatten" lists of lists and the like by using `.SelectMany()`.

Like:

```
var array = listOfLists.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```